# Unit testing VC++ MFC application using CPPUNIT or GTEST

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mfc

I have a project developed in VC++ MFC. every classs is extended by CObject class.
And the default constructors are not defined (may kept protected). I just want to unit test that application, while creating object i was finding runtime errors like Unhand-led exception access voilation at writing and reading locations error. 
Is it possible to test the application which is extending CObject class ???

Comment: Can you give an example? I write unit tests for MFC code with CPPUNIT all of which inherits from CObject, sure it's possible. Sounds like your classes have inter-dependencies which makes it difficult to isolate them for unit testing.

Comment: yes exactly it is having so many dependencies. But the default constructor is not accessible(kept protected). If i create a pointer object to a class, to set a value to setter method i need to initialize it. after initialization also i am getting the debugging error like access violation for reading and writing. I cant provide the example :( . it is completely UI application.

Comment: There must be some factory or similar to create these objects. Also you usually unit test the public side of your class, and this should be possible for you (because it's public). Another thing to try is if you can make your test class a friend of the main class, if you need to access some non-public parts.

Comment: those setter methods are public only. some factory??

Comment: Is the main problem that the UI code is mixed in with your data model? This is typical with MFC applications (but can be avoided).

Comment: yes UI code is mixed with data model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not clear to me what is stopping you doing the testing without some examples (maybe you could invent a simple example to demonstrate your issue). If you want to access the protected class constructor you could do something like this.

```
class A
{
    protected:

    A() {}

    friend class TestClassA;
};

class TestClassA
{
    public:

    void TestA( void)
    {
        A a;
        // test a
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually i was very new to MFC and Unit testing so, i was confusing. I want to use CPPUnit and Google test. CMatch::CMatch(Const A, Cons B, ....) // this is the class how it is defined in this parameter some classes are also passed. { ... the setter methods are used like pmatch and pnewmatch are of same pointer objects int size= pmatch->setsize(pnewmatch->getsize()) .... }